# Can I get the string representation of the formal, rather than actual, template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reflection

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Foo { };
template <typename T> class Bar { };
template <typename NiftyType> class Baz { };
```

In modern(ish) C++, I can use:

```
typeid(Foo).name()  // to will produce "Foo", or
typeid(Bar<int>).name() // to produce "Bar<int>"
```

But that last line gives me the *actual* template parameters; I want the *formal* ones. That is, I want to be able to say:

```
magic<Bar<int>>(); // to produce "Bar<typename T>" or just "T", and
magic<Baz<int>>(); // to produce "Bar<typename Nifty>" or just "Nifty"
```

Can I do this somehow?

**(Obvious) Notes:**

- Not just classes, please.
- I can't instrument the types (if you're upset about this requirement, assume it's not my code). However, a partial solution with some sort of a mixin class is tolerable I guess...
- I do not want to write in the appropriate strings manually into some map.

Comment: IIRC you can refer to some compiler specific [_demangle()_ functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html)., nothing standard though.

Comment: Does the name of the `typename` parameter even has to be the same in every declaration in every translation unit? I don't believe that any of this information is preserved at run-time. Why should it? Maybe as a compiler-specific extension but almost certainly not required by the standard.

Comment: @5gon12eder: As for "why shouldi it" - It's useful for debugging...

Comment: GCC's `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` expands to things like `void Baz<Nifty>::foo() [with Nifty = float]` but I don't see how that's going to help you. You would have to expand that macro in the class body which you say you don't want.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Hmm. But I could have a function taking a Baz, and do the work there, maybe.

Comment: Tricky... What if there's a specialization `template<> class Bar<int>` - I assume you want `Bar<>` for that case. Forward declarations are even worse - I can just write `template<typename U> class Bar;` and pick an entirely different formal name.

Comment: @MSalters: Whatever you give me in that case is fine, as long as it's consistent. I'm actually more interested in the unspecialized cases (although I did ask the general question...)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
class Foo { };
template <typename T> class Bar {
  static const char * debug_name() { return "Bar<typename T>"; }
};
template <typename NiftyType> class Baz {
  static const char * debug_name() { return "Baz<typename NiftyType>"; }
};
```

Then you can define `magic` like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct magic {
  operator const char * () { return T::debug_name(); }
};
```

and use it like you wanted

```
int main() {
  magic<Bar<int>>();
  magic<Baz<int>>();
}
```

I think, based on my C++ experience, that asking for the compiler to generate the `debug_name` for you is quite hopeful. C++ is a nice and useful language but, introspection is definitely not its forte, and you are asking to introspect into a template, not just a type.

Note that if the compiler were forced to support what you are asking as a built-in thing, it effectively prohibits the compiler from parsing template definitions and discarding the (irrelevant) identifier names of the template parameters, and store only a parsed AST form of the template definition, which it might want to do to reduce memory usage. Or it might have to make a second pass over the source to go fetch the names again or something terrible.

I feel there are some far less ambitious things than what you are asking that are not possible, or only kind-of possible using various compiler specific extensions. HTH

Comment: I mean you could use a macro to avoid the duplication, but at what cost... I never said any of this was really a good idea, its just what OP wants :p

Comment: Umm, obviously I meant without me having to instrument the types or write in the strings myself...

Comment: Well, as I explained, `magic` as described is not part of the standard, so if you are also unwilling to do any work of producing it yourself, then its pretty obviously not going to hapen. I mean you can look up the `typeinfo` features in the standard just as easily as anyone else can.

Comment: Note also that even if it's "not your code" you could still accomplish this by making a type trait that holds the debug strings, in your own header file. If you don't want to write the strings yourself, you could make a separate tool outside of the compiler which you make part of your build system that generates the debug strings from an xml spec or something...